# Understanding the order of indexing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

There are 3 columns in a table with 10 million entries. `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. `col1` stores numbers with at most 2 digits, `col2` stores numbers with at most 9 digits and `col3` stores either 0 or 1.

Now, when I compound index in the order (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) I get results(of some select operations with all the 3 columns involved in the where condition- exact values of `col1` and `col3` are specified while a range for `col2`) in around 0.5 seconds while if I order it as (`col3`,`col1`,`col2`) it takes around 10 secs(for the same query).

From what I understand, indexing in mysql concatenates the values in the 3 columns appropriately in the order I specify them and runs a binary search while querying after an initial sort. According to this understanding, mentioning `col3` in the very beginning should be equivalent if not superior to writing it in the order (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) since if I specify `col3=1` or `col3=0` it narrows the search by half.

Please explain the anomaly!

Answer (score 0):

Well its tough to make decision like this but personally I would go with indexing

```
INDEX `compound_index`(col1,col2,col3);
```

If I wouldn't have range scans to be done I would have created

```
INDEX `compound_index`(col2,col1,col3);
```

as col2 most likely have better cardinality

Generally speaking if you don't have range scan to a table columns have better cardinality would become the first column for the index and so on..

In case you have range scan loose index scan works better than covering index
http://www.arubin.org/blog/2010/11/18/loose-index-scan-vs-covered-indexes-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

If your WHERE clause gives a range of values for col2, then anything after col2 in the index is not very useful.

If that's not clear, suppose you index on (col1, col2, col3) and your where clause is "where col1=5 and col2 between 2 and 4 and col3=1". So at best, the SQL engine can go to the place in the index beginning at col1=5, col2=2, and col3=1. Theoretically, it could say that when it gets to the end of col2=2, when it sees the first col2=3, col3=0, it could skip ahead to col2=3, col3=1. Similarly when it gets to col2=4, col3=0, it could skip ahead to col2=4, col3=1. But in practice skipping around in the index is relatively slow. The engine reads the index in blocks, so once it gets a block, if it sequentially searches that block, it already has it all in memory. But to skip it may have to read another block, which means additional I/o operations. I think most SQL engines say that once you give a range, everything after that in the index is not used. So most likely the engine would scan all records from 5,2 to 5,4 and pick out the col3=1 as it went, rather than skipping around in the index.

Given that, while you say that col3 is always 0 or 1. I take it that col1 and col2 have a wider range of values? Let's suppose for the sake of discussion that they each have 10 possible values, and that your range on col2 covers 3 values. And let's assume a relatively even distribution across all values -- there are just as many 1's as 2's, etc.

Then if you index on (col1, col2, col3), the engine can use col1 to immediately narrow the search to just 10% of the index, and col2 to narrow to 30% of that or 3% of the total.

If you index on (col3, col2, col1), then the engine can use col3 to narrow the search to 50% of the index, and col2 to 30% of that, or 15%.

Option (b) has the engine searching 5 times as much of the index as option 1. So yes, it would be slower.